# How to add enable checkbox selection on pinned rows in MUI Datatable?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, datatable

Hi Im looking for a solution to enable checkbox selection on pinned rows. For unpinned rows its totally normal as the documentation says but I cant figure a solution to show for pinned rows. my rows are taking up space for checkbox but its not rendering it.

I tried using the the way mentioned in documentation but it only works for unpinned rows

Comment: Are you referring to the MUI X Data Grid?

Comment: yes referring to MUI X Data Grid